# Resize texture images in SU Ruby

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I need to resize texture image files after COLLADA Export in Sketchup Ruby.

Is there a way to read images (PNG, JPG) from disk, resize them and save them back to disk using plain Sketchup Ruby API?

I know how to do the file read/write, just have no idea about the "image decode, resize, encode" -part.

Most image resize examples I've found involve some image processing library or gem that is not available in Sketchup ruby distribution.. Would be nice to have a portable solution that would be easy to distribute with my SU Ruby plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SketchUp Ruby API doesn't include methods to manipulate images directly.

You can create materials in the model which uses textures, but not just load an image resource.

There is a method you might be able to use: `Material.write_thumbnail` (SU8M1+), based on your description you could iterate over the materials in the model and export thumbnails.

However, the method has an very annoying limitation:

> `Material.write_thumbnail` has a behaviour which limits it usability in
>   some scenarios.
>
> **If you specify a dimension equal or larger to either the width or
>   height of the original, then the method fails. In other words, the
>   resolution argument must be 1px smaller than the smallest unit of
>   either the length or width of the original texture.**
>
> This produces problems with textures with a big ratio between width
>   and height. If you want to produce thumbnails that are max 128x128px
>   and the material you generate the thumbnail for has a texture of
>   64x512px then it fails. As for that given texture the max size for the
>   thumbnail would be 63px (1px smaller than smallest dimension.) –
>   resulting in a thumbnail of 8×63.
>
> For that reason the method should have ideally accepted width and
>   height for the thumbnail in order to be truly usable. Alas. Hopefully
>   this will be improved in a later version.

(More info on material in SketchUp: http://www.thomthom.net/thoughts/2012/03/the-secrets-of-sketchups-materials/#material-thumbnails)

To get real control over images when developing SketchUp plugins you do unfortunately need to use a third party library.

You can look at the plugin "Texture Resizer" by Aerilius who's done a lot of work in this area. http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=323&t=40720#p360679

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately downsizing is one motivation, but most importantly I would need to resize them to exactly power of two dimensions (512x1024, 256x256 etc). So write_thumbnail is of no help. Aerilius's plugin uses ImageMacick, which I was hoping to avoid to not require plugin users to install additional software. Some simple .exe program that I could just include in the plugin folder/distribution would be nice. Or roll my own :(

Comment: If you are familiar, or not afraid of C, then you could find a C library and wrap it up in a Ruby C Extension - unless it's not already one out there. Note that SU Ruby is 1.8 and had some extra quirks, I have a bare bone Hello World example for C Extension for SketchUp Ruby here: https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/sketchup-ruby-c-extension

Comment: Or, these gems you talked about, are they working with Ruby 1.8? I think there are people out there that've managed to get full Ruby working in SU. If you're making this for your own use only it could possibly work. If you're planning on distributing it it won't be ideal.

Comment: I'm am afraid of C.... And yes definitely the purpose is to be able to easily distribute the plugin to less experienced users.

Comment: I have written a BMP reader in SketchUp. I use it to generate terrain meshes and such from bitmaps. I did some hacks where I made SU write out other image formats to BMP so I could read them. No write, but BMP isn't hard to use. BMP isn't a desired format to store it in, but you could hack SU to resave them into another format. And you'd have to do your resize method as well. Very very hacky, but... http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=31339

Comment: Hm. I need to try this! (also wonderful for terrain). With a appropriately resized and saved BMP I could maybe fool write_thumbail to write exactly right sized PNG/JPG. Hacky enough! I'm afraid it would be too heavy for SU/Ruby, but I definitely need to try this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

It appears so if you look here http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/image, the methods `height=` and `width=` should get you what you want.

Comment: That class seems to only allow manipulation of the image 3D representation inside the Sketchup application. It does not allow one to modify arbitrary files from Ruby. Also, the width & height attrributes do not change the image pixel size, only the scale inside the 3D model. I need to change actual pixel size in the image files to be power-of-two...

Comment: Then you may want to look at the sdk beta here http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/downloadsdksubmit though it is in C++ and is no longer under active development

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to read/save SKP. I need to edit PNG/JPG from the somewhat limited Ruby environment in Sketchup.

Comment: The `Image` class refer to the Image entity type in SketchUp.